# Bash-script delete a specific line from a .txt file

Tags: bash

I want to learn how to delete from a txt file the line that contains a word that user typed in a variable
I've tried grep -v but then clears the whole content of the file
Help?!!!

Comment: `sed --in-place '/some string here/d' yourfile`

Comment: If the string is in a variable?

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Comment: Note that `sed` accepts [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression),  so if you do for example something like `sed "/./d"` it does not delete just lines with dots, but deletes everything (as `.` stands for "any character" in a regular expression)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example program how to archive this:

Save this in `example.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
word="$1" 
grep -F -v "$word"
```

Save this in `test.txt`:

```
Hello world
foo bar
baz bau
```

Call the program and feed it with the file test.txt on standard input:

```
chmod u+x example.sh  # Need to do this only once per script (*.sh file)
./example.sh Hello < test.txt
```

Output ("Hello world" line is deleted):

```
foo bar
baz bau
```

Comment: Can I ask you something else?

Comment: If its not related to this answer, better ask a new question for that (if there is not already one out there)

Comment: Its related with what you said about the regular expression in sed

Comment: Go ahead! (Sidenote: you can also use @mention to notify users in a comment)

Comment: I want to replace morse code with english letters for example '. -' with 'a' how to do that with sed @akraf

Comment: If you want to use regex special characters literally (e.g. search for a dot  and not "any character",  you prepend a backslash (this is called "escaping"). So to replace `.-` with sed you do `sed 's/\.-/a/g'` (the `g` means "replace multiple times not just once", the "s/X/Y/" means "replace X with Y") . You need to escape the following characters: `.*^$[]` If you use "POSIX extended regular expressions" (check `man sed`, you can enable those) you have to additionally escape `+?{}()`

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/273318/how-can-convert-characters-into-characters-thatll-produce-beep-noises